# Mysql query - trying to create twitter type timeline with comments

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to achieve a twitter type feed with comments using PHP and MYSQL ie

```
Tweet1
  - Comment1 about Tweet1
  - Comment2 about Tweet1
Tweet2
  - Comment1 about Tweet2
  - Comment2 about Tweet2
  - Comment3 about Tweet2
Tweet3
  - Comment1 about Tweet3
```

I am succesfully managing to loop out the 'tweets' with the associated comments below each tweet. However my problem is that it is looping out my 'tweets' for every number of comments that I have for that particular tweet ie

```
tweet 1
  -comment 1 about tweet1
tweet 1
  -comment 1 about tweet 1
  -comment 2 about tweet 1 (Tweet 1 has 2 comments so loops out tweet 1 two times)
tweet 2
  -comment 1 about tweet 2
tweet 2
  -comment 1 about tweet 2
  -comment 2 about tweet 2
tweet 2
  -comment 1 about tweet 2
  -comment 2 about tweet 2
  -comment 3 about tweet 2 (Tweet 2 has 3 comments so loops out tweet 2 three times)
```

I think the problem is with my join mysql query as Im new to using joins

```
"SELECT tweets.accountno, tweets.id,tweets.tweet,tweets.createdat,tweets.userid,users.name,users.avatar,users.biog,comments.comment FROM tweets INNER JOIN users ON tweets.userid = users.id JOIN comments ON tweets.id = comments.tweetid WHERE tweets.accountno ='123456' ORDER by tweets.ID DESC LIMIT 20"
```

Any ideas anyone? Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Add a `GROUP BY tweets.id` and you should be fine.

Here is how I would wrote the SQL Statement, for simplicity sake I've removed explicit JOIN statements and I'm using implicit ones

```
SELECT 
    tweets.accountno, 
    tweets.id,
    tweets.tweet,
    tweets.createdat,
    tweets.userid,
    users.name,
    users.avatar,
    users.biog,
    comments.comment 
FROM 
    tweets, users, comments
WHERE
    tweets.userid = users.id
AND
    tweets.id = comments.tweetid 
AND
    tweets.accountno ='123456' 
GROUP BY
    tweets.id
ORDER BY
    tweets.id
DESC 
LIMIT
    20
```

Comment: Where would i add this to? I've added it to near the end but now it only loops out one comment for each post 'code'SELECT tweets.accountno, tweets.id,tweets.tweet,tweets.createdat,tweets.userid,users.name,users.avatar,users.biog,comments.comment FROM tweets INNER JOIN users ON tweets.userid = users.id JOIN comments ON tweets.id = comments.tweetid WHERE tweets.accountno ='123456' GROUP BY tweets.id ORDER by tweets.ID DESC LIMIT 20 'code'

Comment: I've edited my answer with an SQL statement, but I haven't tested id